# Creating a login system in Python

Tags: python, authentication

So this is my very first time attempting a project in python, and I decided to try to create a login system. I basically wrote it as one big while loop with a ton of if statements and im stuck because when I am trying to check to see if a username is already in a text file and im not sure how to send the user back to re-enter the username. Also, some of my print statements are printing multiple times and im not quite sure why. So really my question is 1: is there a better/neater way to code this? and 2: why is the program not properly identifying existing usernames and printing certain statements twice (ex. "Error: username is already in use")

Here is my code:

```
file = open('Login.txt', 'a')
newUser = True

while newUser:
    user = input('Are you a new user? y/n, press q to quit: ')
    if user == 'y':
        print('Create an account.\n')
        newUsername = input('Enter New Username(must be at least 4 characters, no spaces): ')
        #check to make sure the username & password fit the correct criteria
        with open('Login.txt', 'r') as e:
            for line in e:
                loginInfo = line.strip().split(',')
                if newUsername == loginInfo[0]:
                    print('Error: that username is already in use.')
                    break
                elif len(newUsername) < 4:
                    print('Error: Not enough characters.')
                    break
                else:
                    print('Username accepted\n')
                    newUsername = newUsername.strip()
                    newPassword = input('Enter New Password (must be at least 8 characters, no spaces): ')
                    if len(newPassword) < 8:
                        print('Error: Not enough characters.')
                    else:
                        confirmPass = input('Confirm your password: ')
                        if confirmPass == newPassword:
                            print('Account Created')
                            newPassword = newPassword.strip()
                            file.write(newUsername)
                            file.write(',')
                            file.write(newPassword)
                            file.write('\n')
                            file.close()
                            print('Your login details have been saved.')
            
    else:
        newUser = False

    if user == 'n':
    userName = input('Enter your username: ').strip()
    #if the username and password match what is in the text file then they can login successfully   
    with open('Login.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            loginInfo = line.strip().split(',')
            if userName == loginInfo[0]:
                passWord = input('Enter your password: ').strip()
                if passWord == loginInfo[1]:
                    print('Login successful')
                else:
                    print('Incorrect password')
            else:
                print('Username does not exist')

    else:
        print('invalid input')
        break
    
#if the user quits, end the program
while not newUser:
    if user == 'q':
        print('Quitting...')
        break
```

Comment: Use functions for different method. then it will be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I don't really know how to append to a dictionary definitely but it works just fine if you create an account and login without closing the program

```
from sys import exit
from os import name, system

users = {}
status = ''

def clear():
    if name == 'nt':       #If Windows clear screen
        _ = system('cls')
    else:                  #If Linux etc. clear screen
        _ = system('clear')

def newUser():
    newUsername = input('Create new username: ')

    if newUsername in users:
        print('\nUsername already exists!\n')
        input('Press [Enter] to continue')
    else:
        newPassword = input('Create new password: ')
        users[newUsername] = newPassword #Append to dictionary(users)
        print('\nAccount created successfully!\n')
        input('Press [Enter] to continue')

def oldUser():
    login = input('Enter username: ')
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    if login in users and users[login] == password: #If user and pass match, continue
        print('\nLogin successful!\n')
        input('Press [Enter] to continue')
    else:
        print('\nLogin failed!\n')
        input('Press [Enter] to continue')

while True:
    clear()
    status = input('Are you a registered user? [y/n] Press [q] to quit\n> ')
    status = status.lower()
    if status == 'y':
        oldUser()
    elif status == 'n':
        newUser()
    elif status == 'q':
        exit()
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some bugs that you should fix:

1. While new user registration: In `Login.txt` file you are iterating line by line, So
   when you add a new user `line` reaches to your `newly added details` and Now it
   executes `if newUsername == loginInfo[0]` this block. That's why you should be getting `Error:  that username is already in use.` after every registration.
2. After successfull registration it should exit the `while` loop.
3. If `user != 'n'` then `print('invalid input')` always executes. That's why you should
   be getting `'invalid input'` always in this case.
4. You can use an `if` statement for exiting in first `while` loop itself instead of using last `while` loop.